# PHP data not returning but it does on die

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
    <?php
 function displayList($additional_preferences_list) {
        $output = '<div class="test">';
            foreach($array as $a) {
                $output .= '<div class="testing">'.$a['name'].'</div>';
            }
    ​                
              $output .= '</div>';
              return $output;
}

displayList($additional_preferences_list);
    ?>
```

If I dd($output); or die the correct values are inputted, multiple testing divs with it's name come out. if I return $output, it is a single testing div without a name. No idea what could be causing this when I die or dd it shows the correct info, if I return or echo it does not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you returning to?

Comment: its not a funtion so why are you trying to return the `$output` here?

Comment: `return` is to return value from _inside a function_.

Comment: It's inside a function... I just cut the crap from it

Comment: Please note that you can also `return` from an included file. But, as I said, the key point is what you do with the returned value at the point when you invoke it.

Comment: With the current code, you're returning from the function,  but you never do anything with the returned value. You don't assign it to another variable or echo it out. What happens if you do. `$output = displayList(); echo $output;`?

Comment: Also, you're calling `displayList()` with no parameters, but `function displayList($additional_preferences_list)` is expecting parameters to output through. Next, the parameters being passed in is `$additional_preferences_list`, but you're iterating through `$array`, which is not defined. At this point, you should be getting 2 errors: `function displayList expects 1 parameter, 0 given` and `variable $array is not defined`

Comment: Please see my answer below. You may have a special character (invisible) messing up php parsing.

Comment: This is just because I copied it to stackoverflow. I am giving the right parameters, if I dd($output) it is all correct.

<div class="test"><div class="testing">Involving Others</div><div class="testing">Negotiating Support</div><div class="testing">Carrying out the Plan</div><div class="testing">Maintaining Morale</div></div> <-- die()

<div class="test"><div class="testing"></div></div> <--- return

Comment: Since you keep editing your code with fixes, I suggest you post your exact code instead of whatever mismatched way you did originally. This will help us by seeing your real code instead of picking out errors with whatever mishmashed code you've tried to obfuscate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

The difference between the response of a function is that `"echo"` sends something from the server to the client(e.g browser), while `"return"` returns something to the caller. But you are not using function here that's why `return $output;` showing nothing to you, but if use debugs like `return var_dump($output);` then you can see the full output of the div string is present [there](https://3v4l.org/ljsWL).

**[return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)**: just exits the execution of the current script.

> return returns program control to the calling module. Execution resumes at the expression following the **called** module's invocation.
>
> **If called from within a function**, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function and returns its argument as the value of the function call. **return** also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

So, You can make a `function` with those statements and `return` like below,

```
<?php
function output(){
    $output = '<div class="test">';
    foreach($array as $a) {
        $output .= '<div class="testing">'.$a['name'].'</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
echo output();
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/sDXDB

Comment: This is what I did. I just cut the function() from when I entered it in stackoverflow.

returning or echoing out the output/function returns a single div class testing with no name. If I dd or die() out the output it has all the correct data.

Comment: Was not me. PS: your demo array works for me if I replace mine with that. There must be something wrong with my multidimensional associative array.

Comment: @Skintest let me clarify, you have `function displayList($additional_preferences_list)` but you are expecting to foreach on `$array`, where is defined ? may be you need to use `$additional_preferences_list` inplace of $array

Comment: i kept my promise. And honestly man, there's gotta be something with his IDE/Text Editor . I swear he had some invisible char throwing off parsing. But I'll let it go. If Sunny's answer works, accept it and let's put this thang to bed!

Comment: @Skintest, also you given code snippet has hidden invalid character. See  when I copy the snippet and paste here :https://3v4l.org/spUsZ

Comment: SUNNY! Thank you!  I tried telling this guy 5,000 times and he didn't listen. It's cool tho, he can get it working.  For other people that have hidden char's , this is a good read:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221042/sublime-text-code-parse-error-for-no-reason-hidden-characters

Comment: @ChrisMedina exactly sir, when I copy his snippet and tried on the online editor it also shows that invalid character that is not visible on his editor, See https://3v4l.org/spUsZ

Comment: @ChrisMedina &Always Sunny - I am using PHPStorm, no notifications or errors there.

It works when I replace my array with your arrray Always Sunny. But I can't get my own array to work. I do suspect something like the hidden character but I can't spot it, neither in your example.

I also don't see the invalid character on your 3v4l link, it only shows these expected errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: additional_preferences_list in /in/spUsZ on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: array in /in/spUsZ on line 4

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /in/spUsZ on line 4

Comment: @Skintest ok just copy your code snippet and paste it on that online editor then you'll see the invalid character :) copy and paste  here https://3v4l.org/

Comment: @Skintest maybe it was a fluke from this particular post. No big deal. I use PHPStorm too. The point is, the syntax is not the problem there was most likely a hidden character throwing things off. Aside from return $output; in a non function but you also mentioned echo didn't work either.  But yea, hidden character death. Ok you solved the problem,  NEXT

Comment: It's not there always sunny, I tried that. It only shows those 3 errors undefined variables and invalid argument as array does not exist.

Comment: Got it working, something messed up with my array does not make sense but ain't got time to go into it. Thanks both of you for helping.